# Issue displaying thumbnail image in VideoView

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-videoview

I'm using VideoView for a web video, and I also have a bitmap object contains the corresponding thumbnail image. Now how should I set the bitmap to the VideoView for displaying the thumnail?

I'm using

```
videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```

But then when I play this video, the video doesn't show, instead it always show this static thumbnail image.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VideoView` is a subclass of `SurfaceView`, which has some special behaviors in terms of its display.  `SurfaceView` contents are actually drawn in a window underneath the view hierarchy and the view simply acts as a hole in the current window so the contents are visible.  Because of this, if you apply anything to the view itself (like a background), it will actually be Z-Ordered on top of the video content.  In addition, if you place anything underneath the `VideoView`, it also will not be visible because of this "hole".

If you want to display content in this space while the video is not playing, it will either need to be in a separate View laid out on top of the `VideoView` that you can hide/show when the video playback state changes, or you need to set/clear the background image you have set when the video playback state changes.

HTH!

Comment: How do you detect that the VideoView starts playing?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
            videoview.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    videoview.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                }
            });
```